# why the dtor is getting called before the scope ends when I call the ctor from main? (Experimental)

Tags: c++, stl

Here I am calling the constructor of class `a` in `main()` without creating an object of that class and it looks the destructor is getting invoked immediately after the call. What is actually happening here? As per my understanding, it’s happening because I have not created an object with some memory? How the dtor is getting called here? How it is implemented? Please share your thoughts on this.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class a{
    public:
        a(){
            cout<<"\nctor";
        }
        ~a(){
            cout<<"\ndtor";
        }
};

int main(){
a(); //why the dtor is getting called before the scope ends?
cout<<"\nctor_called\n";
}
```

o/p of the program:

```
ctor
dtor
ctor_called
```

Answer (score 6):

You're not calling the constructor (you can't directly). You're constructing a temporary object which is immediately destroyed.

Try

```
a anA;
```

Comment: Immediately... Perhaps go for at the next sequence point, which is the end of the statement? Then the explanation can be used for more than just this instance...

Comment: @all, I have new question here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23045077/does-the-constructor-of-a-class-return-a-reference-of-the-class-type-or-just-a-p]

Comment: You want more answers, but you don't accept this existing answer?